# Calculate limit of such sequence $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{n^2+n}{n^2+2n+2})^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

From the first sight it may seem that this limit is equal to 1

Why? Because $\frac{n^2+n}{n^2+2n+2}$ has limit 1. Hence, $\lim 1^n = 1$. What is obviously wrong.

The second idea that came to my mind is that we can see that for any $n$ $\frac{n^2+n}{n^2+2n+2}$ is less than 1. But it does not mean that it's limit is equal to 0. In fact, I created a graph in Desmos and it shows that it's limit is approximately 0.368.

Probably it has something to do with $e$ but I couldn't find the connection.

Comment: limite at $n \to $ infinity or else ?

Comment: @Aryadeva I think that is a sequence hence $n\to \infty$.

Comment: See the penultimate row [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#List_of_indeterminate_forms).

Comment: @Aryadeva yes, acually, $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly, @math-traveler.

Answer (score 2):

The log-limit is$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\ln(1-\tfrac{n+2}{n^2+2n+2})=\lim_{n\to\infty}\tfrac{-n(n+2)}{n^2+2n+2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\tfrac{2}{n^2+2n+2}-1\right)=-1,$$so the original limit is $1/e$.

Comment: @downvoter Why is there a downvote? What is the reason?

Comment: Could you, please, explain your first transition?

Comment: I meant why $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\ln(1-\tfrac{n+2}{n^2+2n+2})=\lim_{n\to\infty}\tfrac{-n(n+2)}{n^2+2n+2}$ this transition is correct?

Comment: @math-traveler Famously $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1$. The proof of this doesn't need Taylor series, as this limit is by definition $\ln^\prime(1)=\tfrac11=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n^2+n}{n^2+2n+2}\right)^n$$
Note that $1^{\infty}$ is an indeterminate form.Substitute $m=\dfrac 1n$
$$\ln L=\lim_{m \to 0} \dfrac 1m \ln \left (\frac{m+1}{2m^2+2m+1}\right)$$
$$\ln L=\lim_{m \to 0}\left(\dfrac {\ln (m+1)}m -\dfrac 1m \ln (2m^2+2m+1)\right)$$
Note that:
$$\lim_{m \to 0}\dfrac {\ln (m+1)}m =1$$
Apply L'Hospital's rule:
$$\lim_{m \to 0}\left(\dfrac 1m \ln (2m^2+2m+1)\right)        =\lim_{m \to 0}\left(\dfrac {4m+2} { 2m^2+2m+1}\right)=2$$
So that
$$\ln L=1-2=-1 \implies L=\dfrac 1 e$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n^2+n}{n^2+2n+2}\right)^n =\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1-\frac{n+2}{n^2+2n+2}\right)^n=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=\frac{1}{e}$$

Comment: Why this transition $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1-\frac{n+2}{n^2+2n+2}\right)^n=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ is legal?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{}}$

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\lim_{n \to \infty}
\pars{n^{2} + n \over n^{2} + 2n + 2}^{n}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}
\pars{n^{2} + n \over n^{2} + 2n}^{n}
\pars{n^{2} + 2n  + 2 \over n^{2} + 2n}^{-n}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}
{\pars{1 + 1/n}^{n} \over \pars{1 + 2/n}^{n}}
\bracks{\pars{1 + {2\over n^{2} + 2n}}^{n^{2} + 2n}}
^{-1/\pars{n + 2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\expo{} \over \expo{2}}\,\pars{\expo{2}}^{0}
= \bbx{1 \over \expo{}} \\ &
\end{align}